# getting first node in xpath result set

Tags: xpath

I am trying to select the first element in a set of resulting nodes after executing an xpath query.

When I do this:

```
//dl
```

I get the following result set:

```
[<dl>​…​</dl>​, <dl>​…​</dl>​]
```

How can I get the first one? Neither of these work:

```
//dl[1]
//dl[position()=1]
```

I am executing this in Chrome's Web Inspector.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use the following:

```
(//dl)[1]
```

The parentheses are significant. You want the first node that results from `//dl` (not the set of `dl` elements that are the first child of their parent (which is what `//dl[1]` (no parens) returns)).

This is easier to see when one realizes that `//` is shorthand for (i.e. expands fully to) `/descendant-or-self::node()/` so that `//dl[1]` is equivalent to:

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/dl[1]
```

...which is more obviously not what you want. Instead, you're looking for:

```
(/descendant-or-self::node()/dl)[1]
```

Comment: i didn't know that was possible. what other examples are there that i can do with (//dl) ?