# Why would an xpath position selection expression return multiple nodes?

Tags: xml, xpath

While working with xpath (which hasn't been very long), I came across something odd.

Shortened version of the xml (The full xml is [here](http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=messages&a=sf-muni) and a snapshot is available on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TTv4w2dv)):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<body copyright="All data copyright San Francisco Muni 2013.">
  <route tag="all">
    <message id="10268" creator="jflynn" startBoundary="1378121400000" startBoundaryStr="Mon, Sep 02 04:30:00 PDT 2013" endBoundary="1378191540000" endBoundaryStr="Mon, Sep 02 23:59:00 PDT 2013" sendToBuses="false">
      <text>Sunday schedules today.</text>
    </message>
  </route>
  <route tag="44">
    <message id="10221" creator="mlee" startBoundary="1377525600000" startBoundaryStr="Mon, Aug 26 07:00:00 PDT 2013" endBoundary="1382857140000" endBoundaryStr="Sat, Oct 26 23:59:00 PDT 2013" sendToBuses="false">
      <routeConfiguredForMessage tag="44">        <stop tag="6420" title="Silver Ave &amp; Revere Ave" />
</routeConfiguredForMessage>
      <text>Stop moved&#10;across Revere&#10;During&#10;Construction</text>
    </message>
    <message id="10222" creator="mlee" startBoundary="1377525600000" startBoundaryStr="Mon, Aug 26 07:00:00 PDT 2013" endBoundary="1382857140000" endBoundaryStr="Sat, Oct 26 23:59:00 PDT 2013" sendToBuses="false">
      <routeConfiguredForMessage tag="44">        <stop tag="6420" title="Silver Ave &amp; Revere Ave" />
</routeConfiguredForMessage>
      <text>Stop moved&#10;across Revere&#10;During&#10;Construction</text>
    </message>
  </route>
</body>
```

The expression

```
//route[1]
```

returned the first `route` node like I expected. However, when attempting to select the first `message` node, with

```
//message[1]
```

multiple `message` nodes were returned rather than just one.

At first I assumed that it was a platform problem, but testing on Android, Desktop Java and a couple of online xpath testers, I'm getting the same results.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Very good and fundamental question.. *+1* for the same..

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting first node in xpath result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199415/getting-first-node-in-xpath-result-set)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both expressions represent the first `route` and `message` child of its parent, respectively.<sup>1</sup> All of your `route`s are siblings sharing a single `body` parent, so the first of these is returned and only that. However each `route` contains its own set of `message` children, the first of which is being returned for every `route` node.

If you need to match the first `message` element in your entire XML document, use:

```
(//message)[1]
```

The parentheses tells the processor to find nodes matching `//message`, then the `[1]` predicate that comes after picks the first out of those nodes. Without them the `[1]` predicate will simply operate based on children of their parent node.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Because I'm a CSS selector junkie: the selector counterparts for your XPath expressions are `route:nth-of-type(1)` and `message:nth-of-type(1)`, respectively.</sub>

Comment: I am still confused.. although you are correct.. In `xpath` expression like `//message[1]` selects the `message` element,whose position is first..But it is ambiguous for me..still..

Comment: @Babai: What is ambiguous about "the first `route` and `message` child of its parent"?

Comment: What I still know that `//message` collect `message` elements wherever you would notice it.. right? If so how does that parent relationship comes out ? I am not getting that point... Why `paren` turns story,where without parent saying something else..? :(

Comment: @Babai: Oh, that's because the parens change the axis by which the `[1]` predicate is operating. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates and http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets

Comment: @BoltClock But don't remove those CSS selectors,those are actually helped me to believe this story but not xpath... :)

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you very much!! http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets is helpful..